# Is there a way to find any one of a set of characters using an excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data that uses a range, or a less than symbol to denote 'between 0 and *number*'. But multiple characters are used for the same purpose.

It looks like below (first two columns), plus a column showing the results I want:

| Country | Average hotdog consumption | Desired output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Madeupaland | 10-200 | 105 |
| Exampledesh | 50—1000 | 525 |
| Republic of Notreal | <1000 | 500 |
| Inventia | ≤5000 | 2500 |

Plus many rows where the data in the second column is purely numerical and doesn't need finessing into a number

I can use this formula to calculate the midpoint where there is a range:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(LEFT(C2,FIND("–",C2)-1),RIGHT(C2, LEN(C2)-FIND("–",C2))), A2)
```

But they only covers one kind of dash(`-` and not `—`). Similarly, if I want to halve the numbers in rows with `<` *and* `≤` I'd need to replicate a formula there.

Is there a way of finding multiple different characters from a set? My understanding is that `find` looks for the whole string of characters. `substitute` is a work around, but I'd have to substitute every different value in the 'character set'.

In regex this would just be `[-—]`.

I'm using Excel 2013 if that matters

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "average the ranges"? You want the *midpoint* for each range? What are your expected results for the dataset you posted?

Comment: @JosWoolley see my edit

Comment: Excel 2013 unfortunately does not have any functionality to allow for mass-substitution. You'd have to nest these replacements *or* use some structure with `IFERROR()`. Something along the lines of: `=IF(OR(LEFT(C2)="<",LEFT(C2)="≤"),MID(C2,2,LEN(C2))/2,IFERROR(AVERAGE(LEFT(C2,IFERROR(FIND("-",C2),FIND("—",C2))-1),MID(C2,IFERROR(FIND("-",C2),FIND("—",C2))+1,LEN(C2))),C2))` maybe

Answer (score 2):

It's not a perfect solution but you can try the following. This replaces those patterns of text with replacements representing which formula to use:

1. Create a Reference Table (I have made this in I1:K5)
   |Pattern |Pattern Name |Substitution Rule |
   |------- |------------ |----------------- |
   |—       |double dash  |/2+0.5*           |
   |-       |dash         |/2+0.5*           |
   |<       |lt           |0.5*              |
   |≤       |lte          |0.5*              |
2. In your third column enter the following array formula (Using Ctrl + Shift + Enter to confirm)
   `=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),B2,"'="&SUBSTITUTE(B2,INDEX($I$2:$I$5,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($I$2:$I$5,B2)),ROW($I$2:$I$5)-1,99))),INDEX($K$2:$K$5,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($I$2:$I$5,B2)),ROW($I$2:$I$5),99)-1))))`
3. Copy your third column and past values into a fourth column
4. Replace all the `'`'s with nothing to evaluate the expressions using Ctrl + H

My [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJahB.png):

| Country | Average hotdog consumption | Desired output | Formula Paste | Output after replacing `'`s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Madeupaland | 10-200 | 105 | `'=10/2+0.5*200` | 105 |
| Exampledesh | 50—1000 | 525 | `'=50/2+0.5*1000` | 525 |
| Republic of Notreal | <1000 | 500 | `'=0.5*1000` | 500 |
| Inventia | ≤5000 | 2500 | `'=0.5*5000` | 2500 |